# Can I use html&css in kivy and python3?

Tags: python, html, css, embedded, kivy

I am currently developing an embedded multi-touch kivy program with python 3.52 in linux. Kivy is good, but I find GUI developing is quite difficult in some way, and animations are often quite laggy.

Also, I found that the program gets quite slow if I put many widgets in a single page. My program contains a lot of widgets so I am also thinking implementing a webview could help.

So I am looking for html and css views in particular screens for better look and feel (and maybe improvement of animation by using transition?).

I've found Cefpython, but it says it works only for python 2.7 and says it is not stable. And it seemed like it is just getting url from the internet not bringing html and css from a file system. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Actually, I don't even need a function as a browser, and all I need is html & css for UI/UX development for couple of screens.

My embedded system doesn't always support internet(meaning it should work without internet). So I can't put any url in it. Once again, I am only trying to use them for styling. Is there a good way of doing it? Or there is no such thing that I want?

Or is there any other recommendation?

Comment: You can load offline files in CEF the same way you can do it in browsers. When you load local html file in Google Chrome you will see that the url is `file:///path/to/file.html`. Use the same url in CEF to load content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you are willing to implement html and css parsers and a web renderers, of course. I would say it's better to find why you find it difficult to do certain things with kivy, and how to remedy that. I've yet to find an UI/layout/template that is easier to do with the web technologies than with kivy, but i'm way more profficient at kivy than at web front end, so i might be biased.

Comment: One of my problems is that if I put many widgets with complex layouts in one screen, it gets very slow. Especially with a popup. I've created something similar to a virtual keyboard which I have many buttons and images in a screen. But I feel user experience is really bad in this way because a button do not respond very well and often ignores touches. So I was thinking maybe those few screens could be replaced with a webview. Also, I find html css more comfortable, because when I have a problem with Kivy. sometimes It takes so much time to solve it. But html css are really easy to deal with.

Comment: In addition, if I can embed a webview in Kivy, I can also reuse the webpage and its look instead of building another screen in kivy.

Comment: Performance problems with too many widgets can be solved with lazy loading and/or recycling (long list of things should always be done with RecycleView), and make sure you don't create bindings that triggers unnecessarily, especially when screens are not visible (you can use on_enter and on_leave to enable/disable things, like animations). It's a bit too generic of a question to answer though, if you show some specific code that you think *should* be fast, but is slow, especially if it's easy to run for other people to analyse, it'll be easier to help see bad patterns and provide alternatives.